# Hide content in Outlook with external CSS

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I inherited a WordPress plugin that sends an RSS feed of content to Mailchimp to generate an email.  This code (which I cannot find the source) is adding an extra logo image which is throwing off the formatting.  I know I should add something like

```
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
```

to the code if I want to hide it in Outlook, but I cannot find the source to add this.  I can only add external CSS.  The usual display: none works in the other email platforms.  Any advice on how to remove this extra image instance in Outlook via external CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is an HTML conditional comment. It can only work embedded in the HTML code. If you want to hide an element from an external stylesheet in the Outlooks on Windows (from 2007 and above), you can use the `mso-hide:all` property. It’s basically a `display:none` but for Word’s rendering engine. Although, contrary to `display:none`, this doesn’t always inherit to `<table>` children elements. In that case you could use a double selector like the following.

```css
.your-element,
.your-element table {
   mso-hide: all;
}
```